# Kuratowski's theorem and non - planar graph

Tags: graph-theory

Hi I have attached two graphs. I am trying to prove that the graph is non- planar. By Kurathowski's theorem, a graph is nonplanar if and only if it contains a subgraph homeomorphic to $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$. Therefore, I extracted the subgraph below which is homeomorphic to $K_{3,3}$. Does this look correct? Please can someone affirm the solution is correct?

**Graph**
[image: Graph1]

---

---

**Solution**
[image: Solution]

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affirmed.

I offer the following (hopefully constructive) criticisms:

- You should recognise *why* this graph drawing is important, e.g. by writing:

> "We can see that the original graph has a subgraph homeomorphic to $K_{3,3}$ by redrawing it as follows: [[blah blah blah]].  Therefore it's not planar by Kuratowski's Theorem."

- There's (arguably) a better way to draw the second graph; see below:

[image: Original graph]

[image: New graph drawing]

These were drawn using [TikZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ).  Here's the LaTeX code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,draw=black,fill=black!20,minimum size=18pt,inner sep=0pt]
  \draw (0,0) node (c){};

  \draw (c)++(0*360/4+135:3) node[vertex] (A){$A$};
  \draw (c)++(1*360/4+135:3) node[vertex] (C){$C$};
  \draw (c)++(2*360/4+135:3) node[vertex] (D){$D$};
  \draw (c)++(3*360/4+135:3) node[vertex] (B){$B$};

  \draw (c)++(0*360/4+135:1.5) node[vertex] (E){$E$};
  \draw (c)++(1*360/4+135:1.5) node[vertex] (G){$G$};
  \draw (c)++(2*360/4+135:1.5) node[vertex] (H){$H$};
  \draw (c)++(3*360/4+135:1.5) node[vertex] (F){$F$};

  \draw[ultra thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- (A);
  \draw[ultra thick] (A) -- (E) -- (H) -- (D);
  \draw[ultra thick] (B) -- (F) -- (G) -- (C);
  \draw[ultra thick] (E) -- (G);
  \draw (F) -- (H);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and for the second drawing:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,draw=black,fill=black!20,minimum size=18pt,inner sep=0pt]
  \draw (0,0) node (c){};

  \draw (c)++(0,3)++(2,0) node[vertex] (G){$G$};
  \draw (c)++(0,3) node[vertex] (A){$A$};
  \draw (c)++(0,3)++(-2,0) node[vertex] (D){$D$};

  \draw (c)++(-2,0) node[vertex] (E){$E$};
  \draw (c) node[vertex] (C){$C$};
  \draw (c)++(2,0) node[vertex] (B){$B$};

  \draw (c)++(-2,1.5) node[vertex] (H){$H$};
  \draw (c)++(2,1.5) node[vertex] (F){$F$};

  \draw[ultra thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- (A);
  \draw[ultra thick] (A) -- (E) -- (H) -- (D);
  \draw[ultra thick] (B) -- (F) -- (G) -- (C);
  \draw[ultra thick] (E) -- (G);
  \draw (F) -- (H);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I'd like to add to Douglas' excellent answer the following minor point: Drawing embeddings in the plane of abstract graphs looks simpler then it really is-you should practice hand-drawing as many as you can-including their subgraphs, complements, duals,etc.